# How to determine size of an object, c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to find out size of this class on a 64 bit system by using WinDbg I get the size 40
which I am not able to understand, as far as I have read MyClass should have

```
8 bytes for SyncBlock
8 bytes for TypeHandle
8 bytes for string reference
4 bytes for Int32
8 bytes for double

= 36 bytes
```

I don't have 10 reputation that's why i am not able to post image.
Anyone has any idea why WinDbg is showing 4 extra bytes ?

Comment: Your class informations need to be stored, too. That may be the 4 byte.

Comment: Just bumped you up over the 10 rep threshold ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that the `string Name` consumes memory too

Comment: @user1567896 that is handled by TypeHandle

Comment: I think in 64 bit builds, it has to align to 8 byte boundaries. So your size will be a multiple 8. 40 is the next 8 byte size multiple.

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, what is its purpose? Just for interest? I can't see any case in which you need to know the exact size of your class. Especially not in an managed environment.

Comment: @user1567896 Yes, just for interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're seeing is the effect of things needing to align to 8 byte boundaries in 64 bit builds (and 4 byte boundaries in 32 bit builds). 40 is the closest size >= 36 that is on an 8 byte boundary. These links talk about object size:

[Of Memory and strings (Jon Skeet's blog)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx)

[Benchmarking C# Struct and Object Sizes](http://blog.softwx.net/2013/01/benchmarking-c-struct-and-object-sizes.html)

[Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)

[How Much Memory Does a C# String Take Up](http://blog.abstractpath.com/2012/08/how-much-memory-does-c-string-take-up.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the padding for types to fit on address boundaries.

This will depends on the types you are using, the runtime and the [StructLayoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used for the type.

if you look at `Int32` with reflector you will see:

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)
```

This [means](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that it **can be noncontiguous**:

> The members of the object are laid out sequentially, in the order in
>   which they appear when exported to unmanaged memory. The members are
>   laid out according to the packing specified in
>   StructLayoutAttribute.Pack, and can be noncontiguous.

The [StructLayoutAttribute.Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value is unset this means that it is 0 (defaultvalue)

A value of 0 indicates that the packing alignment is set to the default for the current platform. It is **usually** 4byte for x86 and 8byte for x64 but it is optimized by the CLR in base of the sistem and those value may vary

You can see it with:

```
#pragma pack(show)
```