# Why does WinDbg shows same size for a c# class and struct?

Tags: c#, windbg

First of all I asked the question about the size of a class which i got an answer and I also understood that.
Now I got confused when I saw WinDbg showing same size for same kind of `class and struct` because I have read that structs don't contain `SyncBlock` then the size for a struct should be 8 bytes less then the size of a class.

My first question:

Is it correct that structs don't have `SyncBlock` field ?

So following is my class:

```
public class MyClass
{
public int Age { get; set; }
public double Amount { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the struct is:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
public int Age { get; set; }            
public double Amount { get; set; }                  
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With WinDbg I get the `size = 40` for both MyClass and MyStruct.

For class I understand it because it has:

```
SyncBlock  = 8 bytes 
TypeHandle = 8 bytes
String ref = 8 bytes
Int32      = 4 bytes
Double     = 8 bytes
Total      = 36 bytes
```

and since it needs to pick 8 byte boundry it becomes 40 bytes, but why is 40 bytes for struct also ?

I am running on 64 bit system. 
Followings are the outputs from WinDbg:
[image] 
[image]

Comment: How is this different than your other question posted yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084232/how-to-determine-size-of-an-object-c

Comment: @paqogomez I din't had struct in my last question.

Comment: Sure, but why do you think they must be different sizes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because I read that struct don't contain SyncBlock field that means size of struct should be than 32 bytes not 40.

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for the `SyncBlock` field?  According to the documentation I'm finding, you will only see this field if there is a synchronization primitive present, like `lock`.

Comment: Alright.  Well have a look here: http://www.discretevector.com/2010/03/syncblocks-and-critical-sections.html.  There shouldn't be a `SyncBlock` at all unless the object is being locked, and there might be more than one `SyncBlock`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But we can't take lock on a value type ?

Comment: No, but your assertion that `SyncBlock` should make the sizes different is wrong, and apparently so is your size calculation.  That 8 bytes is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: it sounds strange to me that SyncBlock is added *dynamically* to the instance of object, as much as I knew it's always present in any instance, ready to recieve lock request. Having this in mind, memory management of the language with automatic memory management is subject to change, so may be in the .net 5.0 the same test will produce different results, which makes basically all this discussion pointless.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Cracking open my copy of CLR via C# (4th edition, page 133) it says unboxed value types "don't have the additional overhead members that every object on the heap has: a type object pointer and a sync block index"

Comment: @MartinSmith: Right.  `SyncBlockIndex`, not `SyncBlock`.  So why is the `struct` 40 bytes, and not the expected 24? (20 bytes for the `string`, `int32` and `double`, plus 4 more to get it to an 8 byte boundary)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - No idea. Not really an area I know much about. I just had a vague recollection of reading something similar to the assertion in the OP before.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I ran the following code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSize()
{
    MyStruct s = new MyStruct();
    Debug.Print(Marshal.SizeOf(s).ToString());
}
```

And got the expected result of 24.

Comment: As I am a beginner, maybe I am not getting it but as you see I have attached screenshot from WinDbg which shows Size = 40 bytes, don't know where is that coming from ?

Comment: Maybe WinDbg is boxing the `struct`, who knows?